# vector::back() but throwing

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I want to bind a reference to the last element of a vector. However, I want to brace against the case where the vector is empty and the reference is invalid. Apparently `vector::back()` doesn't throw (a major oversight to me), which makes me use `vector::at()` instead.

I know that the reference might become invalidated due to heap moves of the `vector`'s elements. But am I right to assume that those moves only take place for resizing operations like `vector::push()` and `pop()` and alike? In this case, it would be fine to use the reference until the next `push()` or `pop()` is encountered, right?

So anyway, I have this:

```
try {
    auto& curr = path_tmp.at(path_tmp.size()-1);
    //...
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: `if (path_tmp.empty()) throw std::out_of_range{}; auto& curr = path_tmp.back();` Longer, but the intent is perhaps clearer this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the vector is empty. If not empty go for the code.

```
    try
    {
         if(path_tmp.empty())
         {// throw an exception.}
         else
         {
             auto& curr = path_tmp.back();
             //use current
         }
         
    }
```

Comment: Just note that in this example, `curr` goes out of scope right away, so it is pretty useless.  I would break `curr` out of the `else` block, by `throw`'ing before declaring `curr` after the `if`, eg: `if (path_tmp.empty()) { throw ...; } auto& curr = path_tmp.back(); // use curr ... `